# Putting quotes into a form field using Javascript

Tags: javascript

This must be so simple but I'm having a brain freeze.

I have a input field :

```
<input value="">
```

I want to populate the value using javascript and the var has quotes " in it. For example, when I populate the value on page load with PHP, I'll just swap " for `&quot;` (or htmlentities, etc).

But when you do the same with js then it just displays `&quot;` (obviously).

Can I just write out " without escape ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape the `"` character in the Javascript string:

```
var str = "I have a \"!";
//Or
var str = 'I have a "!';
```

You can  then assign this string to the `value` property, or to any other property.

Comment: In Javascript, you don't need to HTML-encode anything.  (inline scripts in XHTML should be enclosed in CDATA blocks)

Answer (score 0):

For a pair of double quotes, put them inside single quotes.

```
<input value='""' />
```

Or to set via javascript

```
document.forms[0].elements[0].value = '""';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use single quotes around your value it should work:

```
<input type="text" value='quo"tes' />
```